# PHP 5.4.X is capable of placing setcookie() after HTML markups without "Headers already sent" warning?

Tags: php, cookies

I used to experience **Warning: Cannot add header information - headers already sent** when trying to place `header()` `session_start()` or `setcookie()` after `echo` or any HTML markups.  But when I upgraded the PHP in my local server to *5.4.7* (in *XAMPP 1.8.1*), I don't encounter this warning anymore. Is this normal for PHP 5.4.X?

I tried placing `setcookie()` after some texts and an `echo` in this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Cookie Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Cookie Test</h1>
<?php
    if (isset($_COOKIE['test'])) {
        echo "<p>{$_COOKIE['test']}</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>No cookie..</p>";
        setcookie('test', 'You have a cookie!', time()+300, '/');
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I open the page via *localhost/that-page.php* and refresh ..

> ## Cookie Test
>
> You have a cookie!

In my test environment, `setcookie()` works normally without any warning.  Is something wrong with my settings?  Thank you.

*Win7x64* and *XAMPP 1.8.1* used

Comment: Do you have an `ob_start()` call somewhere? 5.4 certainly didn't change the HTTP protocol.

Comment: must have output buffering turned on by default. in ini `output_buffering = "on"`

Comment: Just noted in my ini that `output_buffering = 4096`. Thanks @Orangepill :) .. How can I tick this question as solved?

Comment: will it let you add an answer for it, then you can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only environmental issue that can lead to to this behavior is for output buffering to be turned on.

This can be done in a number of ways

In the php.ini with

```
 output_buffering = On
```

or

In htaccess/httpd.conf with

```
 php_flag output_buffering On
```

Comment: I'd forgotten it could be in the config. Nice call.